# Golang “net/http” DetectContentType error

Tags: go, content-type, net-http

Use `DetectContentType` to detect the uploaded file `content-type`, but the result is always `application/octet-stream`.this is just the default return in this function.

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library's code is only supposed to detect certain types (like HTML that contains one of a few common tags) according to a certain standardized algorithm--more in https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go. You could use [github.com/rakyll/magicmime](https://godoc.org/github.com/rakyll/magicmime), which uses libmagic and cgo to guess at more file types.